# Sinatra Authorization Extension: NameError

Tags: ruby, sinatra, http-authentication

Can anyone tell me why I get a `NameError - uninitialized constant Sinatra::Default` when calling the `/admin` route?

```
require "sinatra"
require "sinatra/authorization"

set :authorization_realm, "Protected zone"

helpers do
  def authorize(login, password)
    login == "admin" && password == "secret"
  end
end

get "/" do
  "Welcome to the public zone"
end

get "/admin" do
  login_required
  "Welcome to the protected zone"
end
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2, Sinatra 1.2.6 and the [Sinatra Authorization Extension](https://github.com/integrity/sinatra-authorization).

**UPDATE**: OK, I've found the source of the problem at line 25 of the following file:

[sinatra-authorization-1.0.0/lib/sinatra/authorization.rb](https://github.com/integrity/sinatra-authorization/blob/master/lib/sinatra/authorization.rb)

[This fork](https://github.com/sr/sinatra-authorization/blob/master/lib/sinatra/authorization.rb) of the original project solved the problem by replacing `Sinatra::Default.authorization_realm` with `settings.authorization_realm` at line 25. This solves the problem, but I don't understand why. Can anyone explain that to me?

Comment: It's solves the problem because Sinatra doesn't have `Default` class anymore. And if you want to access some settings defined with `:set` you should use `settings.`

Comment: Thanks! Put this comment as an answer and I'll mark it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's solves the problem because Sinatra doesn't have `Default` class anymore. And if you want to access some settings defined with `:set` you should use `settings.` for this.